# How to set up a Polymorphic field in the fields.yaml? October CMS

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, schema, octobercms

In octobercms, I've created a polymorphic table: Phones

- A phone has a contactable_id and contactable_type.
- A phone can belong to a restaurant or a team_member.
- A restaurant has many phones.  A team_member has many phones.

In Restaurant and Team_Member model:

```
public $morphMany = [
    'phones' => [ 'My\Site\Models\Phone', 'name' => 'contactable'] 
];
```

In Phone model:

```
public $morphTo = [ 'contactable' => [] ];
```

My question is how do I build a form for this in assignment in the Phone fields.yaml? Am I setting this up right?

Any help is super appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Repeatable Widget and user something like an array for the field name:

```
phone[][number]:
     label: Contact Phone
     type: text
```